# Two seperate Flask apps communicating in docker containers

Tags: python, rest, api, docker, flask

**EDIT:**

I managed to get it working using `network_mode: "host"` for both containers as suggested below. This is fine for now. However, I feel like it's a bad hack and I would like to learn more about what I'm doing wrong with my containers instead of hacking it.

---

I'm having a problem getting my two Flask apps to communicate in two separate Docker containers. I have ran app.py from `m1` outside of a docker container and it works, but clearly something different needs to be done to communicate outside of a docker container.

I get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
m1_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
m1_1  |     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
m1_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
m1_1  |     response = self.handle_exception(e)
m1_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
m1_1  |     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
m1_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
m1_1  |     raise value
m1_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
m1_1  |     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
m1_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
m1_1  |     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
m1_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
m1_1  |     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
m1_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
m1_1  |     raise value
m1_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
m1_1  |     rv = self.dispatch_request()
m1_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
m1_1  |     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
m1_1  |   File "/app/app.py", line 11, in home
m1_1  |     res = requests.get(url)
m1_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
m1_1  |     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
m1_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
m1_1  |     return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
m1_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
m1_1  |     resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
m1_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
m1_1  |     r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
m1_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
m1_1  |     raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
m1_1  | requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8002): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff58dd1bd30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

app.py from m1

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import requests
import json

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def home():
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:8002/"
    res = requests.get(url)
    dictFromServer = res.json()
    return dictFromServer['message']


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

app.py from m2

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return jsonify({ 'message': 'Hello From M2'})


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

dockerfile(s)

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app
COPY app.py /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

docker-compose

```
version: '3'

services:
      m1:
        build: m1
        ports:
          - "8001:5000"
      m2:
        build: m2
        ports:
          - "8002:5000"
```

Comment: In a Docker container 127.0.0.1 is the container itself, not the Docker host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker containers don't run with the same IP address, so 127.0.0.1 within m1 only resolves to the m1 container.

Two fixes:

1. "network: host" for both containers will use the host network stack, so both m1 and m2 will have the same IP address. "127.0.0.1" will work then.
2. Replace "127.0.0.1" with "m2". This will use the built-in DNS server and resolve the correct IP address for the m2 container. This approach has the added benefit that both containers can use the same port, because they have different addresses.